# How to make a line straight in StarUML

Tags: uml, staruml, tool-uml

I am using the StarUml to draw some component dialog,however I found that it is to difficult to make a straight line straight enough.

In visio, when I want to draw a Horizontal straight line,I can use the "Shift" key in my keybordl,how to do it in StarUml?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've been struggling with this problem too, and have just found the solution:

Select the object you're having straight line issues with, and ensure 'Auto Resize' is not enabled. This will let you resize your object so that all of its anchors snap to the grid. This in turn, will enable your line elbows to match up exactly with the middle of one of your object's edges.

Hope this helps,

Jamie.

Answer (score 35):

I also struggled with this one.

I solved it this way: right click on the line you have issues with. Select Format/Line Style/Rectlinear. Shortcut key CTRL + L.

Juha.

Answer (score 16):

CTRL A + CTRL L should do it :)

Comment: Mac users: Cmd + A, Cmd + L

Answer (score 0):

[image: Select the Actor and Enable these two Options then Select Association]

Select Actor and Enable Two Options in the Image

Hope it Helps Some on.